# JSF Project deployment fails if it contains an JPA entity

Tags: hibernate, jpa, deployment, entity, wildfly

if I add an JPA entity to my JSF-project its deployment fails (without it's succesfull). I use netbeans wizard to create the entity (and I do not extend the code). Further I use maven to build and deploy and Wildfly 8.0 as application server. The deployment is done by wildfly-plugin for maven. It fails with MojoException, which is thrown when a plugin fails to do something, but I don't get any error information (also not with -e or -X parameter).

My hibernate dependencies

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.1.Final</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.1.Final</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

My persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
                           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
                           xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="de.wilhelm_UserManagementPU" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS</jta-data-source>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="create"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I already changed provider-tag from "org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence" to "org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider" (because I use hibernate version 4.3.1, according to https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/JPA+Reference+Guide?_sscc=t#JPAReferenceGuide-UpdateyourPersistence.xmlforHibernate4.3.0)

Answer (score 0):

I found wildfly error messages on my terminal:

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table "APPLICATIONUSER" already exists; SQL statement:                
create table ApplicationUser (id bigint not null, primary key (id))
```

Now its easy to solve